# WPF: {DependencyPropety.UnsetValue} woes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with my bindings which I can't fix! Instead of displaying the required value, I get a {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}.

Here is the `XAML`:

```
    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding DisplayBuyPriceConverted, Converter={StaticResource boolVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Converted Price: {0} {1}">
                    <Binding Path="BuyPriceConverted" Mode="OneWay"></Binding>
                    <Binding Path="CharterSellPriceCurrency" Mode="OneWay"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

Here is what it used to look like, which works fine:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BuyPriceConverted, StringFormat=Converted Price: {0} GBP, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="149" Visibility="{Binding DisplayBuyPriceConverted, Converter={StaticResource boolVisibilityConverter}}" DataContext="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
```

Here is the `C#` which specifies the DataContext:

```
    public AdditionalCostDialogue(AdditionalCostView additionalCostView)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._additionalCostView = additionalCostView;
        this.DataContext = this.AdditionalCostView;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: StringFormat requires its targets to be a string type. What type has `CharterSellPriceCurrency`? Type of `CharterSellPriceCurrency` has to be String.

Comment: @user2250152 no it doesn't `Text` (target) must be of `string` format, which it is. Format parameters can be of any type

Comment: Both VuyPriceConverted and CharterSellPriceCurrency are strings

Comment: @serlingpa do I understand correctly that instead of _Converted Price: X Y_ you see _{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}_?

Comment: hoook up a multiconverter thingy then you ll know what you doing wrong

Comment: Do you see any Binding errors or warnings in Output Window?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that one of my properties is a decimal. Sorry about that guys, I lead you on a wild goose chase. All working now.